# When do I schedule local notification

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

When the user leaves my iOS app, I want to schedule a local notification to remind him about my app. What is a correct place to do it? I cannot choose between

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

and

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Or there's no difference in the case?

I also have a second question. When my app launches (either if user pressed notification, or from launchpad), I should obviously remove all that reminding notifications. I guess I should do it in

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

or

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

or maybe another method? Or it makes no difference again?

Comment: `"I want to schedule a local notification to remind him about my app"` This would do my head in if some app kept telling me about itself, more than likely to the point I would remove it. Seems like a bad thing in my opinion.

Comment: @Popeye I agree, but I have to obey to design docs... I'm just a developer. And this is a very common design as I know.

Comment: Like you say you are just the developer but clients/analysts/designers should listen to developers. If I were you I would just bring it up and let them at least re-think it. But if you have to I would agree with `Wain`s answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it all in `applicationWillEnterForeground`. Remove any old notifications that don't matter now the user it engaged with the app and install any new notifications for after this use session. If the notification fires when the user is still using the app then you don't need to display anything (and the system won't display anything either).

Comment: Strictly speaking, I should wake up user 1 day after he has finished using the app, not 1 day after he has started it. That's why I'm interested would it be ok to schedule new notifications in `applicationDidEnterBackground`?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes, it should be fine.